# Android - Is it possible to hide certain values in ListView and onclick of the list to show all the values?

Tags: android, json, listview

I am consuming a webservice and storing the JSON response in an arraylist. I am displaying the arraylist in a List view in android. My concern here is, say I want only my job id and job status to be displayed in the listview and during the onclick event I need all the data such as job id, job name, job status etc to be displayed.

Currently all the details are shown in the listview itself. I need to hide certain values there.

I tried removing the unwanted fields in the Adapter part. But while doing so, I am unable to retrieve them during the onclick event.

Please help.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        JobMain.this, jobList,
                        R.layout.detail_list, new String[] {"number","name","member","desc","status" }, new int[] { R.id.textView2,
                                R.id.textView4, R.id.textView6,R.id.textView8,R.id.textView10});
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                ListView lv = getListView();
                lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int position, long id) {


                      String reqno = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2))
                              .getText().toString();
                      String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4))
                              .getText().toString();
                      String member = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6))
                              .getText().toString();
                      String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView8))
                              .getText().toString();
                      String status = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView10))
                              .getText().toString();
```

Comment: in your view holder define layout which you want  to play with hide and seek. and on viewHolder.buttonClicked show and hide particular layout (Gone,Visible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
YOu can either hide it in xml by adding this attribute to your view:

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```

OR,

Inside your adapter, set the visibility of the view in question to **gone**.

Either way, inside the onItemClick() of the listview, set the visiblity to **visible** to make it show when the item is clicked

Like this:

**HIDE IN XML**

```
 <!--You can choose to hide it here by setting visibility
to gone in xml like this-->
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**IN CODE INSIDE YOUR ADAPTER getView()**

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder;
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        holder=new Holder();
        convertView=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        holder.editText=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {holder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();}

    //hide the views like this
    holder.editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.editText.setEnabled(true);
    holder.editText.setHint("type");
```

**then to make it visible when clicked,**

inside your getView(), add an onCLickListener to the view you are returning like this:

```
 convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //make the view visible when the item is clicked
            holder.editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Just setting the visibility to "gone" worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You give the ListView.setAdapter(adapter) a ArrayList.
.setOnItemClicklistener() has a position value. Use that to get the object you want from the ArrayList to the next action...

object you_want = ArrayList.get(position);

*And you might want to look into creating your own ArrayAdapter.